# F# difference between let add1 x = x + 1 and let add2 x = x +1

Tags: types, f#

What is the difference between `let add1 x = x + 1` and `let add2 x = x +1`. The accidental removal of space changed the type of function from
    `val add1 : x:int->int` 
to
    `val add2 : x:(int -> 'a) -> 'a`

As far as I understand, the first type statement says `add1` maps `int` onto `int`. But what is the meaning of the second one.

Well, `'a` represents a generic type, but how is the function `'add2'` returning a generic?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

That's a quirk of F# syntax: a plus or minus sign immediately followed by a number literal is treated as a positive or negative number respectively, and not as an operator followed by a number.

```
> 42
it : int = 42

> +42
it : int = 42

> -42
it : int = -42
```

So your second example `let add2 x = x +1` is equivalent to `let add2 x = x 1`. The expression `x 1` means that `x` is a function and it's being applied to the argument `1`, which is exactly what your type is telling you:

```
add2 : x:(int -> 'a) -> 'a
```

This says that `add2` takes a function named `x`, which takes an `int` and returns some `'a`, and that `add2` itself also returns the same `'a`.

Comment: No, it doesn't. Where did you get this idea?

Comment: Coz, as you said in `let add2 = x +1` , `x` is considered to be a function being applied to argument 1. Here `x` was never defined.  Do let me know if I interpreted your statement incorrectly.

Comment: That was just a typo. `let add2 =` instead of `let add2 x =`. Corrected.

Comment: Great, I think I understand now, `add2` has become a higher order function, that takes a function of type `int -> 'a`  as parameter. x is just a placeholder for the parameter. Tried testing the concept using `let add x = x +1;;let func (a:int) = a + 5;; add func;;` and got 6 as answer. Do let me know if this is correct.